# Unable to compile any Android project due to Gradle fail: Could not find javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is really bugging me, I've installed and reinstalled JDK, ADK, Android Studio, and Gradle several times and in various different orders, but I can't get this error to go away. Either I'm not deleting enough when I uninstall, or there's some incompatibility with OS X Yosemite. It's also possible that I'm not pointing Android Studio at the right JDK or ADK... Basically, no idea what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the gradle stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type DefaultClassLoaderRegistry using GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:643)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:597)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:439)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:479)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:227)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.build(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.runBuildInProcess(BuildActionsFactory.java:167)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActionsFactory.java:137)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.createAction(CommandLineActionFactory.java:242)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:232)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.UnknownServiceException: Could not find meta-data resource 'META-INF/services/javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory' for service 'javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'.
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.getFactory(ServiceLocator.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.DefaultClassLoaderFactory.makeServiceVisible(DefaultClassLoaderFactory.java:104)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.DefaultClassLoaderFactory.createFilteringClassLoader(DefaultClassLoaderFactory.java:76)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.restrictToGradleApi(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:50)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.<init>(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry(GlobalScopeServices.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:641)
... 27 more
```

Comment: are you using separate gradle installation, just let android studio download/use its own.

Comment: I did end up removing the separate gradle installation, all the android JDK stuff, and Android Studio, then following the Android Studio install guidelines. I'm hoping that removing everything and starting over once I've installed the release version of Yosemite will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem and read the gradle's **full stack trace** , and found that a jar is missing. The other missing jars, if any will be listed in the **full** stack trace.

the jar in question is commons-lang3.jar which is needed by gradle. I installed the jar in the below step

```
sudo apt-get install libcommons-lang3-java
```

then i ran gradle again and it worked fine.

Comment: Pardon the newbie question, but how do you get the FULL stack trace? I've run into this same error string and trace building a project on a Thoughtworks Go pipeline.