# Gradle Android Build Project Error: Could not find meta-data resource

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Brand new install of the Android SDK, and Android Studio. Brand new project, literally no changes to any file in the project. Working AVD, running 4.4.3 (or something similar). I get the following error:

`Gradle 'Gigviz' project refresh failed.
Error:Could not find meta-data resource 'META-INF/services/javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory' for service 'javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'.`

The best reason I can think of for this error is that I'm missing some component of the `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory` dependency. Has anyone encountered this error before?

I'm on OS X Yosemite, latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: I saw your other question here with more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371301/unable-to-compile-any-android-project-due-to-gradle-fail-could-not-find-javax-x and your Facebook post (which is the only other hit when you Google that error message). This feels like a messed up installation of Java somehow, or your version of Java being incompatible with Gradle -- the stack trace is deep in the guts of Gradle and the Java libraries. This is the Sun JDK? You've tried it with a 1.7 JDK? Not just running Android Studio on 1.7, but compiling with it (the two are separate).

Comment: Xerces problem>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven?

Comment: I've tried Java 7 and 8, I've reinstalled Android Studio, Java, JDK, ADT, and Gradle (and used the version of Gradle bundled with Android Studio) in just about every combination I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download this : `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxxml134jar.htm`
2. Put it inside your JDK folder, in your program files. Something like this :

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib\missioncontrol\plugins`

And see what happens.

Comment: It is the library file of what your gradle or jdk is missing.

Comment: Ok, but why is it missing? I installed it from Oracles' installer multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_fails_with_internal_error_unknownserviceexception_could_not_find_meta_data_resource) on Gradle's forums, same error cause by a duplicate set of jars, inside the JDK's lib/endorsed folder.  Usually when I get any build errors with META-INF in them, it is because a duplicate files somewhere.  Also make sure you are using Java 1.7 or lower.

Comment: I've seen that too, that wasn't the issue, no duplicate files. I tried with several different fresh installs of the JDK.