# Gradle sync failed: Could not find meta-data resource 'META-INF/services/javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

When i try to load/create a gradle project is says "Gradle sync failed: Could not find meta-data resource 'META-INF/services/javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory' for service 'javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'." I did look in to these 2 questions and tried different JDK versions as well but couldn't find a solution.

[Gradle Android Build Project Error: Could not find meta-data resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661323/gradle-android-build-project-error-could-not-find-meta-data-resource)

[Unable to compile any Android project due to Gradle fail: Could not find javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371301/unable-to-compile-any-android-project-due-to-gradle-fail-could-not-find-javax-x)

Any help will be really appreciated to overcome this problem. My computer OS is Yosmite 10.10.5. Current JDK versions i tried,
1.6.0.jdk
jdk1.7.0_79.jdk
jdk1.8.0_73.jdk

Gradle version, 2.11

Comment: Maybe you should post all your gradle code for the project so we know what it's trying to do.

Comment: actually even when i tried to create all new gradlle project this error comes.

Comment: @DougStevenson can u please tell me which code snippets(file) should i post here if i'm creating a all new project. thank you

Comment: If this is happening on a new project, then something must be wrong on your computer.  Sorry, no idea what it could be.